Сайт на Go не видит папку со статичными файлами
На локальном пк собрал проект и все успешно работало, до выгрузки на сервер.
Загрузил на сервер с Ubuntu проект на GO, простенький сайт сделанный для тренировки. Тут я столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой. А именно - сайт не видит папку со css и js. Я пробовал уже по разному указывать пути и полный путь с корня, но никак не пойму где ошибся. На Windows все работало корректно.
Структура проекта:
- Папка проекта
                - static
                            - css 
                            - js
                - templates

Код с маршрутами
func handleRequest() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fileServer))
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/tagDescription", tagDescriptionHandler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server: ", err)
    }
}

Код из шаблона
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Теги и финальный комментарий</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/tag_style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tag_main">

        <div id="title_tag_page">
            <h1>Теги и финальный комментарий</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="tag_content">

            <h3>Теги</h3>

            <script src="static/js/tag_parser.js"></script>
            <script src="static/js/tag_descriptions.js"></script>
            <select id="tagSelect" class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-sm exampl"></select>
            <div id="tag_viem"></div>
            <p id="descriptionSpan"></p>
            <p id="description_popup"></p>

            <textarea name="main_text" id="tag_text" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button id="tag_copy" class="btn btn-secondary">Копировать</button>

        </div>


Здраствуйте, точно уже не вспомню, но пару лет назад я сталкивался с подобным, проблема была в том как я подключал css файлы в html, решилось все добавлением слеша перед путем к css:

На винде так же все работало, а в контейнере нет, если точно помню, то именно этот слеш и заставил все работать
Все закончилось настройкой nginx. Добавил в настройки маршрут до папки с статикой и все завелось.
location /static/ {
    alias /"path"/static/; 
}

